# using timeof() and token() in datastax solr search

Tags: solr, datastax

I am using datastax enterprise 4.5. How can I use cassandra functions like timeof() and token() in solr? I want to display the timestamp that results when using timeof() function on timeuuid entries. I am clueless on where to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

For token() use [restricted query routing](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchRouteQuery.html), new in 4.6. Specify the key as shown below (you can also specify the token ranges themselves but I'm not sure why you would want that):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test.route/select?q=*:*&indent=true&shards.info=true&route.partition=nike|2,reebok|2
```

Or, in CQL:

```
SELECT * FROM test.route WHERE solr_query='{"q" : "*:*", "route.partition" : "nike|2,reebok|2"}'
```

Notice that the second case uses solr_query from CQL. I'm not sure what your exact use case is here but you can probably do something similar from CQL for [time functions of cql timeuuid's](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html).

Comment: Thanks. It never occurred to me.. i will try mixing solr_query and cql commands.